# What is the 'message' keyword in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a data model and on creating a schema 'message' I noticed that SSMS highlights it blue. It can still be created but any attached objects need [message] as the prefix.

Since my solution is a messaging application, I am wondering what the term might refer to since it is not in the published list of keywords for SQL 2000-14 or part of T-SQL standards.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is neither reserved nor in the "future keywords" list, so you can safely use it. See: **[Reserved Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189822.aspx)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some statements using this keyword:

- [CREATE MESSAGE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187744.aspx)
- ALTER MESSAGE TYPE
- DROP MESSAGE TYPE

Comment: Thanks - that shouldn't be an issue but you never know what next year will bring. I'll avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to Service Broker messages/messaging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187744.aspx